# Getting a value from select - Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a question. How to get a value from a $form['item'] so that i can use the value to filter data in form['item_2']. 
Example: 
For option where table looks like :

```
item_id   item_name
1         pencile
2         book
```

So when i chose 2 book it will filter out data in the other form where i have table looking like :

```
  newitem_id  item_id    newitem_name
     1             1         hard
     2             1         soft
     3             2         novel
```

The example code :

```
  function my_module_form($form,&$form_submit){
    $form=array();

    $select=db_query("SELECT * FROM {table_1}");
    $options_one=array();
    foreach($select as $data){
     $options_one[$data ->item_id] = $data -> item_name;
    }


    $form['item'] = array(
    '#title'=>t('Items'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $options_one,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    );



    $temp=1;
    $select = db_query("SELECT * FROM {table_2} WHERE newitem_id=:item_id",array(':item_id'=>$temp));
    $options_two=array();
    foreach($select as $data){
     $options_two[$data ->newitem_id] = $data -> newitem_name;
    }


    $form['item_2'] = array(
    '#title'=>t('Items'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $options_two,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    );
```

Now in the code for $temp i use number one and it gives me hard and soft values in dropdown. But how can i add the selected value from the $form['item'] to the $temp.

Comment: do u want to change the values populated  on `select_box_2` based on the selection on `select_box_1` mate..??

Comment: Jeah when you select in the first box lets say pencil, in the second select box it has to show only hard and soft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use simple `jQuery` in your case or you could use `drupal FORM API #ajax` property.An array of elements whose values can control the behavior of the element with respect to the `Drupal AJAX framework`.`AJAX` (Asynchronous Javascript and XML) is a term used for dynamic communication between the browser and the server, without page reloads.You could find more details on this property [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax).If you find it difficult you could try the examples for developers which drupal provides shows exactly how the values in a dropdown is dependent on another drop down.

[Drupal Developer examples](https://drupal.org/project/examples)

Using Simple Jquery(if your values just static values.If you need to take values from `db`,should be using `jQuery+ajax`)

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VLxtm/)